# How to copy a URL with its title in markdown format?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, copy-paste, url, title

In Firefox 56, how can I quickly copy a URL in the markdown format?

```
[title](url)
```

In theory, VimFx should work, but [it doesn't](https://github.com/akhodakivskiy/VimFx/issues/906#issuecomment-355329720), so I either want to find what's wrong or another method to do this.

Comment: @DavidPostill: thanks for your edit. I wonder why using "how can I" is better than "how to"? I thought the latter is shorter, hence more preferable, especially in question's title?

Comment: Not a lot of difference, but "how can I" is a little better grammar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Copy URL To Clipboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/url2clipboard/) is a good replacement for Firefox Quantum.

[image]

You can assign shortcuts in the addon page

[image]

There are other similar addons (Keyboard Control for Firefox, Text Linky Tool, Format Link), but their HTML output is just the code, not true hyperlink.

Answer (score 5):

#### How can I copy a URL in markdown format `[title](url)`?

You can use the [Copy as Markdown](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/copy-as-markdown/?src=search) extension.

> Copy as Markdown is a browser extension helps you copy the following
>   things as Markdown to your system clipboard:
>
> - ☑️ Current Tab as Link
> - ☑️ A Link in the Page
> - ☑️ An Image in the Page
> - ☑️ An Image that is wrapped with a Link
> - ☑️ All Tabs as a List of Links
> - ☑️ Highlighted Tabs as a List of Links

Source [chitsaou/copy-as-markdown: Copying Link, Image and Tab(s) as Markdown Much Easier.](https://github.com/chitsaou/copy-as-markdown)

Screenshot:

> [image]

Review:

- A very useful extension, particularly for adding links to questions and answers on SE. I wish I'd found it a couple of years ago.
- The Firefox extension works on FF57+.
- There is a Chrome extension as well (I haven't tried it).

Comment: Nice find.  Just downloaded it from the Chrome store and tested it in a Chromium-based browser and can confirm that the Chrome extension works, also.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the following script as bookmark

```js
javascript:(function(){%20window.prompt("Press%20Ctrl+C%20then%20Enter%20to%20close%20the%20dialog",'['%20+%20document.title%20+%20']('%20+%20document.location.href%20+%20')');%20})();
```

then assign a keyword to it (like `c`). Now every time you want to copy just select the address bar, press c and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This doesn't need any add-on

You can also open the console with <kbd>F12</kbd> then run this

```js
window.prompt("Press Ctrl+C then Enter to close the dialog", '[' + document.title + '](' + document.location.href + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Easy Copy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-copy/?src=search)

Features:

- **Rich templates:** HTML, Markdown, BBcode, Wikipedia markups, all links on  page, etc
- **Rich variables:** link title, page title, custom selection, date and time, image alt text, etc
- **Text trimming**
- **Hotkeys support**

You can read more at [its wiki](https://sites.google.com/site/smokyinkproductions/easy-copy/more-templates). It isn't compatible with Firefox Quantum unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The awesome [`Tridactyl`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tridactyl-vim/) extension has the keybinding `ym` for *"yank markdown"*, which does exactly this. It might be overkill for this single piece of functionality, but since the original question mentions `VimFX`, people here might also be interested in the other features it provides.