# Save a shortcut for each open tab

Tags: firefox, shortcuts, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

Is there a way in firefox (via addon or something else) to save a shortcut for all the tabs in a window to my desktop or downloads folder? I don't want to save them into some internal DB of an addon. I want to in one or two clicks save all the open tabs in a window to a bunch of .url files to my desktop that I can put in a folder and come back to in 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a Firefox extension called QuickCut which does exactly that.

But there is no option provided to do this en masse.

[image]

It downloads the website shortcut of the **current** tab as .URL to your Downloads folder. You can designate the default download folder in Firefox settings.

[image]

[QuickCut – Get this Extension for  Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickcut/)

Comment: Thanks, I actually found QuickCut when I posted this, but my question is about doing it for all the tabs in a window at once.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across an extension described in [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1286321/364367) (relating to a different problem) that includes a mechanism to do essentially this.  It's available as both a Firefox and Chrome extension.

[Copy as Markdown](https://github.com/chitsaou/copy-as-markdown) saves links as `[title](URL)`.  It offers a lot of flexibility to save a tab, an embedded image, or other elements.  It adds both a right-click menu option and a toolbar icon.

The toolbar icon provides options for saving the current tab, all selected tabs, or all tabs, the results of which are saved to the clipboard:

[image]

So with a couple of mouse clicks, you can capture titles and links for all of the tabs, paste that into document or note of your choice that supports hyperlinks, and save it.  It pastes as a bullet list.

Comment: Thanks, I've used addons like this before, but I'm looking for something that would save separate shortcut files specifically.

Comment: @xdhmoore, that is going to be a tough requirement.  Dealing with tabs will be browser-specific.  A desktop shortcut will be OS-specific.  And a separate shortcut for each tab doesn't sound like something that would be an ideal solution for most users, so that would make it even less of a target for a developer (if you are saving a collection of tabs, there is probably something they have in common, so most people would likely look for a way to keep them together).  (cont'd)

Comment: Clicking on a hyperlink gets you to an open tab in a default browser, and it's easy enough to save a document to the desktop regardless of OS; so a document containing links to each tab seems more like the kind of solution you are likely to find available (and what you can easily do with available tools).  But good luck with this.